# Enable Python syntax validation/checker in ace editor

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, ace-editor, react-ace

In my web app, I'm using an ace editor with python mode as below:

```js
var editor = ace.edit('aceEditor');
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/python");
editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);
editor.setHighlightActiveLine(false);
editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true
});
editor.setBehavioursEnabled(true);
editor.setValue(`n=int(input("Enter the number of elements to be inserted: "))
          a=[]
          for i in range(0,n):
              elem=int(input("Enter element: "))
              a.append(elem)
          avg=sum(a)/n
          prin("Average of elements in the list",round(avg,2))`, -1);
```

```css
#aceEditor {
 width: 100%;
 height: 260px; 
 border: "1px solid #ddd";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.2/ace.js"></script>
<div id="aceEditor"></div>
```

If `print` is wrongly typed by user, I need to show validation like below:

[image: HTML Syntax validation]

ace editor have syntax validation/check for HTML, JavaScript. But In my case, I need to show errors for python and I'm open to use other editors which supports my requirement and I'm open to use [react-ace](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace) also, In react-ace, can't find a solution demo on [react-ace](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ace-demo)

I came across this [Issue](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2773), where it states Cloud9 uses pylint to display syntax errors. If so, how to enable this in the web app and I guess ace doesn't have built-in support for this? Any help/ guide on this really helpful

Comment: Cloud9 runs pylint on a server, if you want to run pylint in a browser then there is no existing solution for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437738/python-syntax-check-in-ace-editor, if you want  to use on server, you can use some of the code from cloud9

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a couple of options:

1. You could find a Python parser written in Javascript. A quick Google search found [filbert](https://github.com/differentmatt/filbert) for me. I expect there are others.
2. Use a full Python implementation that runs in the browser, then use Python tools to do your validation. I used the [Pyodide project](https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide) to build a browser version of my [Live Coding in Python](https://github.com/donkirkby/live-py-plugin).