# Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:9000/worker-html.js' failed to load

Tags: angular, ace-editor

I am using Ace Editor in my Angular application. It is defined here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ace-editor

Usage:

.html

```
<ace-editor id="editor" class="form-control" formControlName="answer" [ngClass]="validateField('answer')" [(text)]="text"></ace-editor>
```

.ts

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

    this.editor = ace.edit('editor');
         ace.config.set('basePath', '/assets/ui/');
         ace.config.set('modePath', '/assets/ui/');
         ace.config.set('themePath', '/assets/ui/');
        ace.config.setModuleUrl('ace/mode/php_worker','/assets/ui/worker-php.js');
        ace.config.setModuleUrl('ace/mode/coffee_worker','/assets/ui/worker-coffee.js');
        ace.config.setModuleUrl('ace/mode/css_worker','/assets/ui/worker-css.js');
        ace.config.setModuleUrl('ace/mode/javascript_worker','/assets/ui/worker-javascript.js');
        ace.config
.setModuleUrl('ace/mode/html_worker','/assets/ui/worker-html.js');
        ace.config.setModuleUrl('ace/mode/json_worker','/assets/ui/worker-json.js');
        ace.config.setModuleUrl('ace/mode/lua_worker','/assets/ui/worker-lua.js');
        ace.config.setModuleUrl('ace/mode/xml_worker','/assets/ui/worker-xml.js');
        ace.config.setModuleUrl('ace/mode/xquery_worker','/assets/ui/worker-xquery.js');
        this.editor.setTheme('ace/theme/eclipse');
}
```

1) I am getting the following error:

`blob:http://localhos…99f9-cccd48bdb093:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://localhost:9000/worker-html.js' failed to load.
    at blob:http://localhost:9000/9446350d-625c-418b-99f9-cccd48bdb093:1:1`

Why is this?

2) I couldn't find the purpose of these worker files, and from where they get included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do two things to make the code work

in code, add path

```
ace.config.set('basePath', '/assets/ui/');
    ace.config.set('modePath', '/assets/ui/');
    ace.config.set('themePath', '/assets/ui/');
    ace.config.set('workerPath','/assets/ui/');
```

Add the following code in `angular.json`

```
"assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ],

            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/ace.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/theme-eclipse.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/theme-monokai.js",
              "./node_modules/ace-builds/src/mode-html.js"
            ]
```

All `ace` files are in `/node_modules/ace-builds/src/`. the `glob` line makes them available at the `outDir` of where `Angular` will create the final build. In my case it is `../public/ui` from where I build the angular code. So all the `ace` files will actually go to `../public/ui/`. Reason I am using `assets` is because I am using `Play` server which accesses assets using `assets` in the path. So to get files, it will call for example `localhost:9000/assets/ui/worker-html.js`. In the `play` application, I use a route to map all `/assets/...` requests to `/public/...` path

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

Comment: Hi @Manu Chadha, i hv used above approach . but i am getting content security policy error

`scripts.83c3b7679895c818396b.js:213 Refused to create a worker from 'blob:https://test.com/204376e5-12a4-4591-afcb-c2f1ae988278' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src self http: 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

Comment: This too `Could not load worker DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at 'blob:https://test.com/d130d6c2-aea8-43c8-bc89-9b476e241850' is denied by the document's Content Security Policy.`

Answer (score 16):

This is for react-ace figured it would maybe somewhat similar for angular fixed it for me,

```
<AceEditor
 setOptions={{ useWorker: false }}
 ...props
/>
```

Basically disables the serviceWorker. Adding a `webpack-resolver` increases number of files and compile time. This [thread](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/issues/725) helped me a lot.

Comment: this solution worked with me on Reactjs app

Comment: Thanks bro .... helped me solve the issue i was facing in next js !

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the output path in angular.json file.

```
 "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "worker-javascript.js",
                "input": "./node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/",
                "output": "/"
              }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

my code in angular 7.1.2 was like:

```
<div ace-editor [(text)]="backupData.content" [mode]="'javascript'" [theme]="'eclipse'" [options]="options"
       [readOnly]="false" [autoUpdateContent]="true" [durationBeforeCallback]="1" (textChanged)="onChange($event)"
       style="min-height: 200px; width:100%; overflow: auto;"></div>
```

and in .ts was:

```
options = { maxLines: 1000, printMargin: false };
```

according to @Shujath, i change options to :

```
options = { maxLines: 1000, printMargin: false, useWorker: false };
```

and problem solved.
thanks @Shujath.
also I review @SAURABH answer and I changed angular.json and it works.

```
 "assets": [
          "src/assets",
          {
            "glob": "worker-javascript.js",
            "input": "./node_modules/ace-builds/src-min/",
            "output": "/"
          }
        ]
```

thanks  @SAURABH